# line break in notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++

I am building a standard Filewriter in Notepad++. For readability I want linebreaks in the text I'm writing to my file:

```
    import java.io.*;

class CreateAFile {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        try{
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("MyText.txt");
            writer.write("This is de first part of my line                          
            and here the second part");
            writer.close();

            }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for "line breaks in Notepad++" and found a lot of replacing and String output answers (like putting in the \n, \r, \r\n or \n), but none of them works.

The output in the file doesn't concern me at the moment (so one line, or more lines). I want the readability in my Notepad++ to be better at the moment.

What am I missing here? Thanks for your replies in advance.

Comment: For the record: you're not "building a FileWriter".

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out...Still new and trying to find out correct language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
writer.write("This is de first part of my line"                             
            + "and here the second part"
            + "one more part");
```

or for faster work:

```
   writer.write(new StringBuilder("This is de first part of my line")
                .append("and here the second part")
                .append("one more").toString());
```

Comment: This won't add a new line in the file.. I think you mean `.appendLine(...)` instead of `.append(...)`. And the first part is just for more readible code, `"some string" + "some string"` has nothing to do with the output..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen example there "first PART of line" and the "second PART", so is should be one line. And `\n` should work in the result file, so i think he wants exactly the code new lines.

Comment: @TEXHIK Ah, I misread the question.. In that case your first answer is indeed correct.